# Probability: Intersection and Union of sets

Tags: probability, measure-theory, problem-solving, independence

I want to show the following statement,

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Let $E_1,\dots , E_n \in \mathcal{F}$. Let, $$\mathcal{C}=\left\{F \in \mathcal{F}: F = \cap_{i=1}^{n}F_i, F_i \in \left\{E_i, E_i^c\right\}, i = 1, . . . , n\right\}$$
For all $1\leq i_1 < \dots < i_k\leq n$ , where $k = 2, \dots , n − 1$, show that $\cap_{i=1}^{k}E_{i_j} = \cup\left\{F ∈ \mathcal{C} : F \subset \cap_{j=1}^{k}E_{i_j}\right\}$.

I don't see how to visualize the following set $\cup\left\{F ∈ \mathcal{C} : F \subset \cap_{j=1}^{k}E_{i_j}\right\}$.

Any ideas or leads?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the $E_1,\dots,E_n$ as some "basic"-events. Then $E_1^c$ means $E_1$ doesn't happen, $E_1 \cap E_2$ means $E_1$ and $E_2$ happen; $E_1 \cup E_2$ means $E_1$ or $E_2$ happen.

Hence, $\mathcal{C}$ is the collection of events, where you have an oppinion on every basic-evenent $E_1, \dots, E_n$ -- whether it happend or not. Whereas in a set of the type $\cap_{i=1}^{k_j}E_{i_j}$ you know that the $E_{i_j}$ happend, but there may be some basic-event, where you don't have know.

The set $\left\{F ∈ \mathcal{C} : F \subset \cap_{i=1}^{k_j}E_{i_j}\right\}$ is the collection of events, where you know about every basic-event (they are in $\mathcal{C}$) and which are compatible with $\cap_{i=1}^{k_j}E_{i_j}$ (this is what the inclusion says).

The equality
$$\cap_{i=1}^{k_j}E_{i_j} = \cup\left\{F ∈ \mathcal{C} : F \subset \cap_{i=1}^{k_j}E_{i_j}\right\}$$
basically says that you can write the event $\cap_{i=1}^{k_j}E_{i_j}$ as the union of the "compatible" basic-events. It's just an elementary set-theory/logic fact, where you don't need any measure- or probabilty theory for the proof. The direction $\supset$ should be clear. For the reverse inequality, I give you an example, which should make clear how to prove this:

Let $n=3$. Then $E_1 \cap E_3$ is not in $\mathcal{C}$. But $E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_3$ and $E_1 \cap E_2^c \cap E_3$ are both in $\mathcal{C}$ and you have $E_1 \cap E_3 = (E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_3) \cup (E_1 \cap E_2^c \cap E_3)$, which gives you the equality in that example.

The full proof is exactly the same idea, but with somewhat more notation. Feel free to ask if you get stuck there :)

Edit: The crucial point is the following. Let $\ell_1,\dots,\ell_p$ the remaing indezies, i.e. $\{1,\dots,n\}$ is the disjoint union of $\{i_1,\dots, i_k\}$ and $\{\ell_1,\dots,\ell_p\}$. Then
$$ \cap_{j=1}^{k}E_{i_j} = \cup\left\{\bigcap_{j=1}^{k}E_{i_j} \cap \bigcap_{m=1}^p F_{\ell_m}: F_{\ell_m} \in \{ E_{\ell_m}, E_{\ell_m}^c  \} \right\}  $$
and
$$\left\{\bigcap_{j=1}^{k}E_{i_j} \cap \bigcap_{m=1}^p F_{\ell_m}: F_{\ell_m} \in \{ E_{\ell_m}, E_{\ell_m}^c  \} \right\} \subset \left\{F \in \mathcal{C} : F \subset \cap_{i=1}^{k_j}E_{i_j} \right\} $$

Comment: So for the $\supset$ proof, as you said, is quiet obvious. But for the example you gave $n=3$, it shows the equality directly rather than the other part $\subset$, right?

One other question. I got the point that you said in the example, how about a general $n$? should we like go case by case in the same reasoning? Or is it more like a very formal proof (induction maybe)? (I am sorry if my question wasn't clear)

Comment: In my example it proofs the equality, that true. But (maybe depending on how you write it down) you only get one inclusion. I wounldn't use induction. I'll add sth to my answer, bc its too much tex-code for the comment...

Comment: Okay I got your point. I tried to write a short version of the proof following your thoughts and it kind of coincide with your last lines. Probably one last question to ask you,  What would your guess be about this set $\bigcup\left\{\cap_{i\in\{1,\dots ,n\}\setminus\{i_1,\dots ,i_k\}} F_i :\quad F \in \mathcal{C} ,\quad F \subset \cap_{i=1}^{k_j}E_{i_j} \right\}$, is it equal to $\cap_{i\in\{1,\dots ,n\}\setminus\{i_1,\dots ,i_k\}} E_i$?

Answer (score 0):

I will give an answer based on @user940347 idea.

Let $I=\left\{1,\dots,n\right\}$, $I_k=\left\{ i_1,\dots,i_k\right\}$ and $\tilde{I}_k=I\setminus I_k$. We have the following,
\begin{align*}
    \cap_{j=1}^kE_{i_j}&=\cap_{i\in I_k}E_i\\
    &= \bigcup\left(\cap_{i\in I_k}E_i\cap_{j\in\tilde{I}_k} 
    \tilde{F}_j\right) \quad \text{where $\tilde{F}_j\in\left\{E_j,E_j^c\right\}$}
\end{align*}

We have $\left(\cap_{i\in I_k}E_i\cap_{j\in\tilde{I}_k}\tilde{F}_j\right)\in\mathcal{C}$ by definition of $\mathcal{C}$ and of course $\left(\cap_{i\in I_k}E_i\cap_{j\in\tilde{I}_k}\tilde{F}_j\right)\in \cap_{i\in I_k}E_i$ by definition of intersection.

Therefore the $\subset$ is proved.